# How can I make runas.exe (Windows) wait until the program it starts exits?

Tags: windows, runas

That is, I want runas to exit only after the program that it runs exits.

There is no `/wait` argument to runas.exe.  I've tried lots of permutations of `start /wait` with it and nothing works.

I have to use `runas` because I need elevated privileges for the program, so I need to start it like this:

```
runas /user:administrator /savedcred /env update.exe
```

where `update.exe` is my program. `runas` is being called from a Cygwin Bash, as well, to make it even more complicated.

I'm on Server 2008 R2.

Well, this is one way to solve it.  It uses the `Sysinternals` `pslist` program and Bash:

```
do_update()
{
if test -d c:/; then
    case `hostname` in
    thor*)
        update="runas /user:administrator /savedcred /env \".\\update.exe\""
        ;;
        *)  update="./update.exe" ;;
    esac
    $update
    while pslist -e update > /dev/null 2>&1; do
        echo waiting for update.exe to finish...
    sleep 3
    done
else
    ./update.sh
fi
}
```

It is horribly hacky, though, mainly because it cannot get the exit status of the program back to the caller.  That is a huge problem, IMO.

Comment: What do you mean for program to be started?  There is process allocated etc, ready to receive windows messages, has a window showing, etc.  There are different levels of "started".

Comment: Perhaps I should have said "wait for it to finish".  I want runas to return when the program finishes.

Comment: Elevated privileges should persist through a programs run time regardless of whether or not RunAs is still running. Are you experiencing specific issues that seem to indicate otherwise? If so, please detail.

Comment: Did you tried using cmd /wait runas -"arg..." ?????

Comment: cmd /wait ... doesn't work because runas itself exits *immediately*.

Comment: @music2myear The issue isn't with the elevation.  It's with the waiting.

Comment: What is NOT working? What is it not doing that you want it to do (meaning update.exe)?

Comment: @KCotreau It is not waiting.

Answer (score 0):

RunAs does **not elevate** a process, but merely runs the process with target user credentials.  But this does not run the process with an elevated token. What you are trying to do with Runas is impossible.

To do this, you need to use either PowerShell, VBScript or download the [Elevation PowerToys](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.06.elevation.aspx) from Technet.

**Edit:**

For example, type:

```
runas /user:<i>Workadmin</i> cmd
```

Then run fsutils, which requires administrator privileges; access denied.

Or try:

```
runas /user:<i>workadmin</i> "mmc.exe gpedit.msc"
```

Access denied.

I'm surprised you haven't noticed this because it causes all sorts of issues when running scripts.  If scripts launch other scripts which then requires elevated permissions, then it will break.  This is also an issue with VBScripts and PowerShell scripts.

Comment: Are you sure? By running under the context of a user with the credentials you need, it gives the process elevated status - I use this frequently :/

Comment: 2008 R2 has UAC. If UAC is off, then yes.  If it is on, then you are wrong.

Comment: I agree with William.  I use this all the time and get elevated status and UAC is on.

Comment: Ah nm. You are using the builtin Admin account.  The built Admin account has auto-elevate on by default.  It is off on my machine and I just assumed it was off by default on the Server editions.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question was about `runas` waiting for the commande to complete.